# AKS Integration with ACR Different Subscription

Tags: acr

We have ACR in our subscription . Our client has AKS in their subscription and totally different region too. We need to give them permission to pull our images from their AKS. What is the recommended way of doing this ?

In case of future issue we should be able to remove the client pulling images from our ACR.

Comment: In this scenario ACR and AKS are running on two different AD tenants.